# Can you get the timestamp from a Firebase realtime database key?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

According to this [blog post](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-04-28-best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html), firebase array keys are created using a timestamp:

> It does this by assigning a permanent, unique id based on the current timestamp (offset to match server time).

Is there a way to recover this timestamp for use later, given the key?

Comment: Even if you could retrieve the timestamp from the key, it would be a bad idea. The timestamp is used to generate a unique, chronologically ordered sequence. If somebody at Firebase figures out a more efficient way (whichever subjective definition of efficiency they happen to choose) to accomplish the same goal, they might change the algorithm for `push`. If your code needs a timestamp, you should add the timestamp to your data; not depend on it being part of your key.

Comment: If you feel like reverse engineering: the push Id is generated from the timestamp in `NextPushId` here https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.1.0/firebase-debug.js (you can search for "NextPushId = function" to find it quickly.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**As I said in my comment, you should not rely on decoding the timestamp from the generated id. Instead of that, you should simply store it in a property in your Firebase.**

That said, it turns out to be fairly easy to get the timestamp back:

```js
// DO NOT USE THIS CODE IN PRODUCTION AS IT DEPENDS ON AN INTERNAL 
// IMPLEMENTATION DETAIL OF FIREBASE
var PUSH_CHARS = "-0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
function decode(id) {
  id = id.substring(0,8);
  var timestamp = 0;
  for (var i=0; i < id.length; i++) {
    var c = id.charAt(i);
    timestamp = timestamp * 64 + PUSH_CHARS.indexOf(c);
  }
  return timestamp;
}
var key = prompt("Enter Firebase push ID");
if (key) {
  var timestamp = decode(key);
  console.log(timestamp+"\n"+new Date(timestamp));
  alert(timestamp+"\n"+new Date(timestamp));
}
```

I'll repeat my comment, just in case somebody thinks it is a good idea to use this code for anything else than as an exercise in reverse engineering:

> **Even if you know how to retrieve the timestamp from the key, it would be a bad idea to do this in production code. The timestamp is used to generate a unique, chronologically ordered sequence. If somebody at Firebase figures out a more efficient way (whichever subjective definition of efficiency they happen to choose) to accomplish the same goal, they might change the algorithm for `push`. If your code needs a timestamp, you should add the timestamp to your data; not depend on it being part of your key.**

### Update

Firebase documented [the algorithm behind Firebase push IDs](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-02-11-firebase-unique-identifiers.html). But the above advice remains: don't use this as an alternative to storing the date.

Comment: Let me just reiterate that this is a bad idea. Use Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP. Store the timestamp in the data. It's sortable, query-able, and reliable.

Comment: I think it answers the question rather well. I just don't think it's the right question. (although I asked the same one years ago; this is actually a dup but I couldn't find the original)

Comment: Hence accepted-but-downvoted is the proper course of action. Unless you find the duplicate, in which case you should mark the question as a dupe. :-)

Comment: The algorithm used to generate keys is now documented in the Firebase blog: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-02-11-firebase-unique-identifiers.html. The consensus among Firebasers seems to be that they still recommend to not depend on this in production and use `Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` instead. In fact the blog post reiterates that fact and explains another reason why that approach is preferable.

Comment: This is a big help if you need to add timestamp. Based on this you can recreate all timestamps for old values. So, I upvoted. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version of [Frank's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27910048/425694) re-written in Swift (4.2 at the time of writing.)

Just to be clear, my use case for this was to patch my old models with no timestamps (`createdAt`, `updatedAt`.) I could just throw in random dates in them just to save me some headaches. But then that wouldn't be relevant to their models. I knew that there's an element of time baked into these auto-ids based on what I've read from other articles.

```
let PUSH_CHARS = "-0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

func decode(autoId: String) -> TimeInterval {
  let substring = autoId.substring(toIndex: 8)
  var timestamp = 0
  for i in 0..<substring.length {
    let c = Character(substring[i])
    timestamp = (timestamp * 64) + PUSH_CHARS.firstIndex(of: c)!.encodedOffset
  }
  return TimeInterval(exactly: timestamp)!
}
```

Grab the Playground-ready code here: https://gist.github.com/mkval/501c03cbb66cef12728ed1a19f8713f7.

Answer (score 0):

And in python

```
PUSH_CHARS = "-0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

def get_timestamp_from_id(id):
    timestr = id[0:8]
    timestamp = 0
    for idx, ch in enumerate(timestr):
        timestamp = timestamp * 64 + PUSH_CHARS.index(ch)
    return timestamp/1000
```