# Can a timestamp be extracted from the Firebase GUID

Tags: firebase

According to the Firebase API reference "The unique key is based on a timestamp, so list items will automatically be ordered chronologically..."

My question then is can the timestamp be extracted from this Firebase generated unique key, e.g. the "**-JRHTHaIs-jNPLXOQivY**" below:

```
{
  "posts": {
    "-JRHTHaIs-jNPLXOQivY": {
      "author": "gracehop",
      "title": "Announcing COBOL, a New Programming Language"
    },
```

The intent is to not have to create a separate timestamp field if not needed.  If it is possible, what's the formula to decode it?

Comment: I'd guess *based* on a timestamp doesn't mean it's decodable. I'd bet they're doing some sort of one-way hash that includes a timestamp in the process. Even if it's decodable, without some sort of guarantee that they won't change the GUID generation in the future, you'd be foolish to rely on it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27908312/can-you-get-the-timestamp-from-a-firebase-array-key/27910048#27910048