# Firebase getting server timestamp

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am trying to structure my firebase database as such.

**year/month/date/message**
e.g. 2017/08/26/message

Therefore, I need to get the firebase server time to set the new message reference path.
I have used `Firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` but it returns a placeholder that only gets converted to epoch time during inserting. Therefore my `'createdAt'` field is correct. But I need a way to create my desired path structure.

```
let epoch = Firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
console.log(`epoch : ${epoch}`) // it returns an object
let date = new Date(epoch) // date creation fail here
console.log(`date : ${date}`)
let messagesRef = db.ref(`messages/${date.getFullYear()}/${date.getMonth()}/${date.getDate()}`)
let newMessage = {
  createdAt: epoch    
}
messagesRef.push(newMessage)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are ways but weird, easiest way I can think of is push the message, and then grab the message to get the timestamp you just pushed.

Another way is get the key of a new pushRef

```html
messagesRef.push().key
```

And then get timestamp from decoding the firebase key (since they are generated by timestamp)
[decode firebasekey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27908312/can-you-get-the-timestamp-from-a-firebase-array-key)

@cartant state you can use server clock offset

```html
var offsetRef = firebase.database().ref(".info/serverTimeOffset");
offsetRef.on("value", function(snap) {
  var offset = snap.val();
  var estimatedServerTimeMs = new Date().getTime() + offset;
});
```

Comment: Push keys are created on the client. They use the client's time, but take the clock skew relative to the server into account. It would be simpler to just use the clock skew to adjust the local time. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#clock-skew

Comment: @cartant agreed

Comment: Great comment @cartant. Using the skew (I'd forgotten that it's documented) is probably worth its own answer.

Comment: Not sure if I implied your answer correctly. So you are suggesting that I push a 'dummy' message to firebase and retrieve it's time via `messagesRef.push().key`?