# Why python posting one data will appear 6 times on Firebase database

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I just use the simple code to post a data to firebase, but I don't know why it appears 6 times on firebase realtime database.

```
from firebase import firebase

url = "https://xxx.firebaseio.com/"
fb = firebase.FirebaseApplication(url, None)

fb.post("/posts", {'ID':123})
```

I run "python fb.py" one time only.

However the result is:

[image]

I am very confused.

Comment: I've never seen Firebase automatically write multiple push IDs for a single `POST` call. The most likely explanation is that you (or someone else) really did run the script multiple times. I quickly [decoded a few of the keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27908312/can-you-get-the-timestamp-from-a-firebase-array-key), and the top write `-LOhRKx_wN72PX8GOCQx` was around `Sat Oct 13 2018 05:40:38`, while the bottom write `-LOhRLGNNs-6fAdUQQqy` was `Sat Oct 13 2018 05:40:39`

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to update this field or create a new entry with a unique ID when you run your code?
Maybe try using `fb.put()` instead.
`fb.post()` is the equivalent of .push() in the JavaScript API, so it creates a unique ID for you. `fb.put()` is equivalent to .set() and will just set the data.

Comment: I want to insert a new data called id:'123', but I appear 6 times of this data. It has error when using 'put()'. **put() takes at least 5 arguments (4 given)**