# How to avoid keys other than the ones generated by push() - Firebase Security Rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I was searching through the documentation, but I couldn't find anything about preventing anyone from making up their own keys when writing new data to Firebase Realtime Database. How can I make sure that keys are generated by Firebase's `push()` method?

Comment: The format and code for generating such keys is quite well documented, for example here: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html But the keys are also largely random, so what are you trying to enforce with this? String length? Order? Randomnes?

Comment: I know about Push ID and saw the example code of generating ids, but my problem is how I can ensure that client uses the generated id. It's possible to validate the key based on what a Push ID would be like, but to a certain extend. Wouldn't it be vulnerable if one builds a logic relying on the client-generated keys to be Push ID, so that is unique and in order?

Comment: If you read that article, it explains the stellar low odds of duplicates. But if you want to protect against overwrites in the database, you can do that with a `".write": "!data.exists()"` in your rules. Hence my question what you specifically you're worried about. The more concrete you can be, the more likely it is we can answer.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'll try to be more specific. Let's say server expects an exact Push ID when new data added, but someone figures out the api and writes their own keys like 000000, ######, aaaaaaa... I'd like to know if there is a way to validate it just like we use `newData.val() === now` when we want to enforce a timestamp field to be `Servervalue.TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: It **is** possible to decode the timestamp from a push key. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27910048 for an example. You could probably enforce this (at least partially) in security rules, but I've never done that myself.