# Firebase Push Keys Are in Incorrect Chronological Order

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

According to [Jacob Wenger](https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/Tk7fOa-RMwM)

> Firebase push IDs are 100% guaranteed to sort in chronological order
> (if they don't, it's a bug)

I just ran into this bug. FYI this is the first time I've ever seen this happen. Every time a new message appears in the database, my listener listens for the last/most recent message, then shows it to both users. This keeps the convo live. However, as explained below, -NgWdYah0llBo4rryDd3(msg_1) and -NgaAh8_4jwiS2SR2JJq(msg_2) are stuck at the bottom, and every new message appears before them so the users never see any of the messages they type unless they close the activity and come back.

I use the following to create my push key Ids

```
val messageId = Firebase.database.reference.child("messages").push().key.toString()

val map = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()
map["timeStamp"] = System.currentTimeMillis()
map["message"] = "msg_xxx"

val messagesRef = "/messages/$messageId"
// ... other refs

val rootDbRef = Firebase.database.reference // The reason I'm using this is because this is an Atomic update with other refs
rootDbRef.updateChildren(map)
```

As the messages were posted, msg_1 and msg_2 have an incorrect order. I sent them first but they went to the bottom as if they were sent last. Every message that I sent after those 2 messages are posting before them when every other message should come after them.

```
// all of the timeStamps are the real actual timeStamps

(posted 1st)
-Nga9itauQTt6UiPu8Tc
 message: "msg_1"
 timeStamp: 1697075800547

(posted 2nd)
-NgaAh8_4jwiS2SR2JJq
 message: "msg_2"
 timeStamp: 1697076054763

// ...

(posted 9th)
-NgWdYah0llBo4rryDd3
 message: "msg_9"
 timeStamp: 1697076620975

(posted 10th)
-NgWe5beMpBEyx24eeqQ
 message: "msg_10"
 timeStamp: 1697076768177
```

In the database the order is incorrectly showing as:

[image]

The actual order should be:

```
-Nga9itauQTt6UiPu8Tc
-NgaAh8_4jwiS2SR2JJq
-NgWdYah0llBo4rryDd3
-NgWe5beMpBEyx24eeqQ
```

To be a little clearer, msg_1 and msg_2 were posted correctly, in the correct order.

msg_3 to msg_10 were also posted in the correct. However they are all appearing before msg_1 and msg_2, which shouldn't happen based on the Firebase Push Keys. In the image above **-NgWdYah0llBo4rryDd3**(msg_9) and **-NgWe5beMpBEyx24eeqQ**(msg_10) should be at the bottom of the list in the database.

I'm not sure what epoch times are associated with **-Nga9itauQTt6UiPu8Tc** and **-NgaAh8_4jwiS2SR2JJq**, but whatever they are they are way in the future because even after a hour of noticing this error, no matter what message I post, those 2 messages stay at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase push keys are generated client-side based on:

- the current client-side time
- the clock skew (offset by the time-difference between the client and server) that was determined when the connection was established.

Based on that, the only way I can imagine a significant difference is if there's a difference between the skew that the client determined when it connected to the server and when you call `push()`.

I recommend checking the skew of the clients that generate these outlier push keys by listening for the `.info/serverTimeOffset` as shown in the documentation on [clock skew](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#clock-skew).

If you have a scenario where you can't tolerate this type of problem, you'll want to write a [server-side timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#server-timestamps) in the child nodes too, and order the results on that value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm sending messages back and forth between a real device and the simulator. I just checked, the simulator is the one the created those 2 anomaly messageIds. Based on what you said, do you think this is just a simulator issue? On a side note, some of the messages between 3-10 were also created on the same simulator, and those were correct.

Comment: Check the skew value. If my hypothesis is correct, the client may have reconnected in between those incorrect and correct values. :(

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm on top of it. Cheers!

Comment: I'm curios about something. Those 2 outliers, is there anyway you or anyone at Firebase can find the actual time associated with them? It's really odd that it's 2 hours later and they are still appearing at the bottom even though the messages that I just pushed are posting in the correct order (except before them). Seems like they are wayyyyyy ahead in the future.

Comment: Hmm... I wrote a gist for that once I think, or maybe it was a jsfiddle. Let me see if I can dig it up. --- Ah. I posted it here even. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27908312/can-you-get-the-timestamp-from-a-firebase-realtime-database-key

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted that answer. I'll play with it this weekend. Very good explanation on why not to use it in production

Comment: Well... it's definitely uncommon for push keys to not work, I hardly ever see this happen. But when it happens, a reconnect should fix it - unless it's a rogue client.