# How to Order and Listen to Child Node Results based on ServerValue.TIMESTAMP?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, timestamp

I ran into a [situation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77277424/4833705) where the Firebase Push Key IDs weren't in chronological order.

In his answer, @FrankvanPuffelen said

> If you have a scenario where you can't tolerate this type of problem,
> You'll want to write a server-side timestamp in the child nodes too,
> and order the results on that value

My current code:

```
fun sendMessage(fromId: String, toId: String) {

    val messageId = Firebase.database.reference.child("messages").push().key.toString()

    val messageMap = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()
    messageMap["timeStamp"] = System.currentTimeMillis()
    messageMap["message"] = "..."
    messageMap["fromId"] = fromId
    messageMap["toId"] = toId
    messageMap["messageId"] = messageId

    val messagesRef = "/messages/$messageId"
    val fromIdRef = "/user-messages/$fromId/$toId/$messageId"
    val toIdRef = "/user-messages/$toId/$fromId/$messageId"

    val atomicMap = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()
    atomicMap[messagesRef] = messageMap
    atomicMap[fromIdRef] = 1
    atomicMap[toIdRef] = 1

    val rootDbRef = Firebase.database.reference
    rootDbRef.updateChildren(atomicMap)
}
```

which results in:

```
-messages
    -NseAh8_4jwiZ9CR9XXw
       message: "..."
       messageId: "-NseAh8_4jwiZ9CR9XXw"
       timeStamp: 1696624119048
       // ...

-user-messages
    -user_A
       user_B
          -NseAh8_4jwiZ9CR9XXw: 1
    -user_B
       user_A
          -NseAh8_4jwiZ9CR9XXw: 1
```

Whenever either user sends a new message to the other user, I have a listener that listens to **user-messages/the_current_uid/other_uid/last_message_Id**, thus all of the new messages are currently shown to both users:

```
var userMessagesObserver = Firebase.database.reference.child("user-messages")

fun listenForNewMessages() {

    query = userMessagesObserver
                .child(fromId) // fromId is the current user
                .child(toId)   // toId is the other user they are messaging with
                .orderByKey()
                .limitToLast(1)

    listenerRefHandle = query?.addChildEventListener(object : ChildEventListener{

        override fun onChildAdded(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {

            val lastMessageId = snapshot.key.toString()
            fetchMessage(lastMessageId)
        }
    })
}

fun fetchMessage(messageId: String) {
    // fetch message from messagesRef using the messageId then display it
}
```

As per Frank's suggestion, once I looked into using `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`, it can't be used as a `key`, only as a [value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47275974/4833705), so I can't figure out how to (1) add it to the **user-messages/the_current_uid/other_uid/last_message_Id** node because no matter what happens, the child's key will always be the messageId eg. *-NseAh8_4jwiZ9CR9XXw : 1*, and as stated in my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77277424/4833705), that can go terribly wrong. (2) How can I listen to the new `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` that's added, so I know when to display a new message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @FrankvanPuffelen recommended, it's best to use a server-side timestamp in the child nodes and order the values according to that timestamp.

As I see in your code:

```
messageMap["timeStamp"] = System.currentTimeMillis()
```

The `timeStamp` property holds the value of the current milliseconds, but that value is generated on the machine that runs that code and **not** on the server.

> As per Frank's suggestion, once I looked into using ServerValue.TIMESTAMP, can't be used as a key, only as a value.

Yes, there is no way you can use a `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` as the name of the node. Why? It's because a `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` is an object, better said a [Map](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/), and the keys in the Realtime Database are always a strings.

Although this might have been possible, it wouldn't be much of a help. The timestamps in the Realtime Database are represented by long numbers, so if you set a number as a key, it will become a string, and if you want to order strings, you won't get the desired result, because when you order strings, the strings are ordered [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

So as said before, the best option you have is to add the timestamp as a value of a field. In Kotlin, it will be as simple as:

- [How to add Firebase Timestamp when adding an object of a data class to the Firestore in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68600269/how-to-add-firebase-timestamp-when-adding-an-object-of-a-data-class-to-the-fires/68608800#68608800)

Now, you can create a query and [order the results by child](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/database/Query#orderByChild(java.lang.String)).

There is a down-site, unfortunately, there is no way you can specify the direction, as you can do it in Firestore. So you cannot ask the Realtime Database to return elements in descending order. So the trick here is to add negative values. This means that when your order has negative elements ascending, you get the desired results.